# Conditional data binding with Alloy

Tags: binding, titanium, appcelerator, alloy

I want to know if is possible to do conditional data binding in Alloy.

I want to change a word to plural if the value that i'm binding is more than 1
Imagine this 2 examples:
"Your rating is 1 star".
"Your rating is 2 stars".

Depending on the number I want to change the word "star" to "stars". How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Your question was not totally clear, with what exactly you want, but considering a few cases I will try to give you the solutions for all the cases:

> **Case 1** : Consider the rating value to be stored in a variable

```
var rating = 1;     //whatever value you get from service or any other source;

if(rating > 1){
    $.label1.text = "Your rating is " + rating + "stars";
}
else {
    $.label1.text = "Your rating is " + rating + "star";
}
```

> **Case 2** : This case can be similar to the first case only difference will that we can use the string.xml
>
> Your string.xml will have values :

```
<resources> 
    <string name="ratingStat">Your rating is</string>
    <string name="star">star</string>
    <string name="stars">Stars</string>
</resources>
```

> In js file

```
var rating = 1;     //whatever value you get from service or any other source;

if(rating>1){
     $.label1.text = L("ratingStat") + " " + rating + L("stars");
} else {
     $.label1.text = L("ratingStat") + " " + rating + L("star");
}
```

> **Case 3** : if you receive the whole string and you want to change the value then.

```
var ratingStat = "Your rating is 2 star.";      // Whatever value you get from service or any other source.    

var ratingVal = ratingStat.substr(15,1);

if (ratingVal > 1) {
    ratingStat = ratingStat.replace("star", "stars");
}

Ti.API.info('ratingStat ' + ratingStat);
```

***Note*** : If non of the answer matches your requirement, in this case please elaborate the question what exactly your question is about.

**Good Luck, Cheers**